# Jenkins pipeline is not moving on for Flask app

Tags: python, flask, jenkins, devops

What makes Jenkins move to the next stage.
So guys...Hello, I am developing a pipeline as a project for the following - using jenkins.

Fetch a flask app from github, build the app and run a simple test to check the output.

So I get stuck at the build stage, My Flask app does build and run successfully, However it does not progress to the test stage.

I feel - that Jenkins feels the stage is not complete once my flask app completes building......

Can anybody shed some pointers please

If I go to "console preview" on Jenkins, I see the Flask app is built and running, and gives me the Flask connection banner and logs.....and it does not move from there.....It doesnt get to display  *echo 'building'*

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/main']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '9c4a0738-2cf4-4485-b83c-f8683dab65a0', url: 'https://github.com/clinton-pillay7/jenkins-flask-project']])
            }
        }
    
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                git branch: 'main', credentialsId: '9c4a0738-2cf4-4485-b83c-f8683dab65a0', url: 'https://github.com/clinton-pillay7/jenkins-flask-project'
                sh 'pip uninstall -y pymongo'
                sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
                sh 'pip install pymongo'
                sh 'python3 flaskhome.py'
                echo 'building'
                
                }
                
                }
            
        stage("Test"){
            steps{
                echo "the job has been tested"
            }
                
            }
    
    }
    }
```

What I have tried: Trying to get Jenkins to read a "200" status from the build so it progresses, which does not work

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins pipeline stage runs the commands one-by-one. The previous one must complete before the next one starts. Your Jenkins pipeline starts a flask server that begins to wait for requests and stalls the pipeline.

With Python/Flask, you really do not need build stage. There's a plenty of resources on how to start server and run tests that can be found with Google One such is [Flask & Jenkins example](http://pkuwwt.github.io/programming/2020-03-16-jenkins-continuous-integration-testing-for-flask/), in which the Flask server is started at the start of testing stage, tests are run, and finally the server is shut down and the pipeline ends.